# How to prove the inequality $f(z) = \varphi_1(-z) - \varphi_2(-z) = \frac{e^{-z} - 1}{-z} - \frac{e^{-z} + z - 1}{z^2} > 0, \forall z > 0$?

Tags: limits, inequality, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

The exponential $\varphi(z)$ functions usually appear in the Butcher tables of exponential time difference Runge-Kutta methods for differential equations.

They are given by
\begin{align}
\varphi_j(z) = \frac{1}{z^j}\int_0^z\mathrm{e}^{(z - s)} \frac{s^{j-1}}{(j-1)!} \mathrm{d} s.
\end{align}

Let $\varphi_0(z) = \mathrm{e}^z$, it can be easily calculated that
\begin{align}
&\varphi_{k+1}(z) = \frac{\varphi_k(z) - \frac{1}{k!}}{z},  \quad \varphi_k(0) = \frac{1}{k!}, \\
&\varphi_1(z) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^z - 1}{z}, \\
& \varphi_2(z) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^z - z - 1}{z^2}.
\end{align}

Now consider the function $f(z) = \varphi_1(-z) - \varphi_2(-z), z > 0$,

It can be easily verified that
\begin{align}
\mathrm{lim}_{z\rightarrow 0} \varphi_1(z) = 1, \\
\mathrm{lim}_{z \rightarrow 0} \varphi_2(z) = \frac{1}{2}, \\
\mathrm{lim}_{z\rightarrow -\infty} \varphi_1(z) = 0, \\
\mathrm{lim}_{z \rightarrow -\infty} \varphi_2(z) = 0,
\end{align}
then we have
\begin{align} 
\mathrm{lim}_{z \rightarrow 0} f(z) = \frac{1}{2},  \\
\mathrm{lim}_{z \rightarrow +\infty} f(z) = 0.
\end{align}

The derivative of $f(z)$ is
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned} 
f'(z) &= \frac{ z^2 e^{-z} + 2z e^{-z} + 2e^{-z} -2}{z^3}  \\
 & = \frac{2e^{-z}(z^2 / 2 + z + 1 - e^z)}{z^3} \\
& < 0, \quad \forall z> 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

**Q:** How to prove that $f(z) > 0, \forall z > 0$?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have it down?
If $f'(z)<0$ for all $z>0$, then $f$ is strictly decreasing on $[0,+\infty)$. Let's proceed arguing by contradiction.

Suppose there were some $z_0>0$ with $f(z_0) \leqslant 0$.
We would then have $f(z) < f(z_0)$ for all $z > z_0$.

You could then take any $z_1 > z_0$, so that $f(z_1) < 0$ (strictly).
Finally, this would mean $f(z) < f(z_1) < 0$ for all $z>z_1$.

This would contradict $\lim_{z\to+\infty}f(z) = 0$ and imply that our original assumption (that there is some $z_0>0$ with $f(z_0)\leqslant 0$) is wrong, proving hence that $f(z)>0$ for all $z>0$.

Comment: Hi Fimpellizieri, thank you very much for your comment. For example, consdier $g(x) = e^{-x}, x> 0$,  the derivative is $g'(x) = -e^{-x} <0,  x> 0$. That is, $g(x)$ is strictly decreasing, but we know that $g(x) > 0, x > 0$.

Comment: Yes, the same argument can be made for $e^{-x}$.

Comment: I have edited to hopefully make it clearer and more step-by-step.

Comment: Fimpellizieri, thank you very much for your answer. Really appreciate it.